# Skype integration with the native contacts?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, skype

I tried adding Skype information to my contacts and there's a gray circle showing up beside the Skype username. I can then deduce that it is indicating my contact as offline. However, there seems to be some inconsistencies. On some contacts, I can see three options below them namely:

- IM with Skype
- Call with Skype
- Video call with Skype

However, on other contacts, there aren't any options below their Skype usernames. And also, another inconsistency is the status. My contacts would show up as online on the Skype app but will still show the gray circle on the Contacts app. This happens fairly most of the time which defeats the purpose of it having an indicator there in the first place. At times though, it would correctly and show a yellow circle on online contacts.

I want to know why it's behaving like this and if there's any way to make it less **buggy** than how it is right now.

Also, can't I just click on the Skype username on the Contacts app and have the Skype app open up their profile? It seems easier that way instead of adding the three Skype actions I stated earlier.